# Uppercase letters in UILocalNotification's alertAction property

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have a problem with UILocalNotifications. I want to show a text with upper case letters as the title of the action slider of a local notification.

Here is my code:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotif.alertBody = @"Lorem ipsum";
localNotif.alertAction = @"Foo with UPPERCASE letters.";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

The problem is, that the alertAction text is shown only in lowercase letters.

Is there any way to show uppercase letters in the action slider?

Edit: To be more precise, the action slider is the text below the body text (in this case "Lorem ipsum")

Comment: Have you been able to find out something about this problem?

Comment: Sadly No. But there are few other changes I recognized, which are a bit strange. For example the way the alertActions are displayed in iOS 8.